# Scrapy spider not saving items to PostgreSQL database

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, scrapy, amazon-rds

I have some Scrapy spiders that get properties advertisement info and stores on database. It was already working when I start in the company, but we had to migrate our DB from GCP to AWS, so I've updated the `pipelines.py` file with the new DB credentials.

The thing is: I'm not able to run it on scrapinghub 'cause it tooks more than 1 hour (free account limit). So I've tried to run locally with `scrapy crawl my_spider` command. Evertything looks nice on log, but the database wasn't updated. I've tried with a local DB and nothing happened too. So it isn't the fact of the DB is hosted on cloud, but I think I'm missing something to run it from my local machine.

Here is my `pipelines.py`:

```py
import psycopg2


class TutorialPipeline(object):
    def open_spider(self, spider):
        hostname = 'my-database.xxxxxxxxxx.sa-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com'
        username = 'my_user'
        password = 'my_pwd'
        database = 'my_db'
        self.connection = psycopg2.connect(host=hostname, user=username, password=password, dbname=database)
        self.cur = self.connection.cursor()

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.cur.close()
        self.connection.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        try:
            self.cur.execute("insert into imoveis(area_construida,\
                imovel_tipo, datacriacao, dataatualizacao, cidade,banheiros,\
                bairro, area_terreno, estado, fonte, garagem, imovel_id, latitude,\
                longitude, numero, preco1, preco2, transacao1, transacao2, quartos,\
                rua, suites) values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,\
                %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) ON CONFLICT (imovel_id) DO UPDATE set\
                dataatualizacao = %s, preco1 = %s, preco2 = %s, transacao1 = %s,\
                transacao2 = %s", (item['area_construida'], item['imovel_tipo'],\
                item['datacriacao'], item['dataatualizacao'], item['cidade'],\
                item['banheiros'], item['bairro'], item['area_terreno'],\
                item['estado'], item['fonte'], item['garagem'],\
                item['imovel_id'], item['latitude'], item['longitude'],\
                item['numero'], item['preco1'], item['preco2'],\
                item['transacao1'], item['transacao2'], item['quartos'],\
                item['rua'], item['suites'], item['dataatualizacao'],\
                item['preco1'], item['preco2'], item['transacao1'],\
                item['transacao2']))
        except psycopg2.IntegrityError:
            self.conn.rollback()
        else:
            self.connection.commit()
            return item
```

Here is my `items.py`:

```py
import scrapy

class TesteSQL(scrapy.Item):
    imovel_tipo = scrapy.Field()
    datacriacao = scrapy.Field()
    dataatualizacao = scrapy.Field()
    cidade = scrapy.Field()
    banheiros = scrapy.Field()
    bairro = scrapy.Field()
    area_terreno = scrapy.Field()
    area_construida = scrapy.Field()
    estado = scrapy.Field()
    fonte = scrapy.Field()
    garagem = scrapy.Field()
    imovel_id = scrapy.Field()
    latitude = scrapy.Field()
    longitude = scrapy.Field()
    numero = scrapy.Field()
    preco1 = scrapy.Field()
    preco2 = scrapy.Field()
    transacao1 = scrapy.Field()
    transacao2 = scrapy.Field()
    quartos = scrapy.Field()
    rua = scrapy.Field()
    suites = scrapy.Field()
```

`settings.py`:

```py
BOT_NAME = 'AvaieiCSI'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['AvaieiCSI.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'AvaieiCSI.spiders'
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1216.0 Safari/537.2'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
# Log Messages
LOG_LEVEL='INFO'
FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING='utf-8'
# Configure maximum concurrent requests performed by Scrapy (default: 16)
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 32

# Configure a delay for requests for the same website (default: 0)
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay
# See also autothrottle settings and docs
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 1
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   'AvaieiCSI.pipelines.TutorialPipeline': 300,
}
```

My scrapy log:

```
(env_scrapy) λ scrapy crawl vivareal
2019-08-22 15:16:40 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.0 started (bot: AvalieiCSI)
2019-08-22 15:16:40 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.4.1.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.5.2, w3lib 1.21.0, Twisted 19.7.0, Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 19.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019), cryptography 2.7, Platform Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0
2019-08-22 15:16:40 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'AvalieiCSI', 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1, 'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8', 'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'AvalieiCSI.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['AvalieiCSI.spiders'], 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1216.0 Safari/537.2'}
2019-08-22 15:16:40 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2019-08-22 15:16:41 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2019-08-22 15:16:41 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2019-08-22 15:16:41 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['AvalieiCSI.pipelines.TutorialPipeline']
2019-08-22 15:16:41 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-08-22 15:16:42 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-08-22 15:17:42 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 50 pages (at 50 pages/min), scraped 602 items (at 602 items/min)
2019-08-22 15:18:42 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 97 pages (at 47 pages/min), scraped 1226 items (at 624 items/min)
2019-08-22 15:19:42 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 146 pages (at 49 pages/min), scraped 2466 items (at 1240 items/min)
2019-08-22 15:20:42 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 193 pages (at 47 pages/min), scraped 3509 items (at 1043 items/min)
2019-08-22 15:21:42 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 241 pages (at 48 pages/min), scraped 4412 items (at 903 items/min)
2019-08-22 15:22:42 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 289 pages (at 48 pages/min), scraped 9010 items (at 4598 items/min)
2019-08-22 15:23:42 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 339 pages (at 50 pages/min), scraped 13992 items (at 4982 items/min)
2019-08-22 15:24:04 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-08-22 15:24:04 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 181496,
 'downloader/request_count': 357,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 357,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 11086385,
 'downloader/response_count': 357,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 356,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 22, 18, 24, 4, 493796),
 'item_scraped_count': 15610,
 'log_count/INFO': 14,
 'request_depth_max': 52,
 'response_received_count': 357,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 356,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 356,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 356,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 356,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 22, 18, 16, 42, 722996)}
2019-08-22 15:24:04 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

As you can see there are a lot of items. Any idea why it's finishing and not saving? Am I missing some command after running `scrapy crawl my_spider`?

Comment: You're usina only a except psycopg2.IntegrityError. Can you try a broad  exception like Exception? Maybe It can  give you more informarmation.

Comment: I've changed to Exception but there is nothing wrong on log. Looks like the same I posted above.

Comment: Have you checked if `process_item` ever gets called, e.g. by logging a message? (it’s probably called, you just need to make sure) Similarly, have you checked if your rollback method is getting called every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not completely sure, but it looks like your code is falling to exception and rollback then.
Try to use log/print/PDB to debug your pipeline.

I would also recommend using [Peewee ORM](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/) which is tiny and fast. A really nice thing for such tasks.

BTW. The pipeline `process_item()` should return an item if I'm not mistaken. So you should move `return item` out of `else` block or probably use `finally` for it.

Comment: It  makes sense. @C. S. F. Junior Are You  using any sequence in your db? If the transaction is rolling back the sequence will be increasing.

Comment: After debugging I've treated a feel exceptions and now it's working fine! It was rolling back for more than one exception according with the data. Thank you!